# How To make TableLayout same width and wrap content

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

i am try to make application when the TextView changed value, then the TableLayout and Text View will wrap content in one line text, table row below the first TableRow will follow the first TableRow width.

This is My Code xml :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="I want This Layout in one line " />

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="This textview in one line" />

        <!-- Column 3 -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="This to" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- more rows
    <TableRow ... </TableRow>
    -->
</TableLayout>
```

[image: My Layout]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hai @JaydeepPatel thanks for your answer, but its still not work, should i try to use wrap content in my text view too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these two lines to your textview:

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

that way when your text will be longer than what can be adjusted in one line it will ellip at end

and if you're using LinearLayout then a simple hack will be set your LinearLayout width to wrap_content then parent Layout width will become equal to biggest child. Then you can set the width of the small child to match_parent and it'll match the width of required view.

Comment: Hai, thanks for your answer, but thats not i hope. I want to make textview will follow with the text (full)

Comment: you've given weight 1 to your textView so it has fixed width so when your text is longer than that width either you've to move to next line to show the text or you've to ellip the text

Comment: ok, sir thank you i get it, but how to make my second TableRow same width with first TableRow?

Comment: are you going to change text dynamically or it'll be static??

Comment: Dynamically sir, i am using RecyclerView

Comment: if you use Relativelayout as your parent layout then you can do it real easy just put these two lines in your second tableLyout :
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableRow1"